# Test if Material-UI withStyles component with required PropTypes is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I'm new to unit testing and having trouble testing whether a Material-UI withStyles component with required propTypes is rendering children Material-UI elements.

profile.js

```
const StaticProfile = (props) => {
  const { classes, profile } = props
}

return (
  <Paper>
    <div>
      <MuiLink></MuiLink>
      <Typography>
      <LocationOn>
      <LinkIcon>
      <Calendar>
    </div>
  </Paper>
)
```

profile.test.js

```
describe('<StaticProfile />', () => {
  let shallow;
  let wrapper;

  const myProps = {
    profile: {},
    classes: {}
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    shallow = createShallow();
    wrapper = shallow(<StaticProfile {...myProps} />);
  })

  it('should render a Paper element', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Paper).length).toBe(1);
  })
})
```

However, it doesn't seem like the component is rendered at all with this error received.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 1
Received: 0
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `wrapper.dive().find(Paper)` because StaticProfile is wrapped by the `withStyles` higher order component.

Try this:

```js
it('should render a Paper element', () => {
  expect(wrapper.dive().find(Paper)).toHaveLength(1);
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!